# aggregation in Java and methods in main method

Tags: java, aggregation

I have such code which works well, but I wonder why method area is not possible to put in the main method

```
public class Circle {
    Operation op;
    double pi = 3.14;

    double area(int radius) {
        op = new Operation();
        int rsquare = op.square(radius);
        return rsquare * pi;
    }


    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Circle c = new Circle();
        double s = c.area(5);
        System.out.println(s);

    }

    class Operation {
        int square(int n) {
            return n * n;
        }
    }
}
```

Example which doesn't work:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    double area ( int radius){
        op = new Operation();
        int rsquare = op.square(radius);
        return rsquare * pi;
    }
```

Comment: Java does not allow nested methods/functions - that's just a design decision of the language. Some other languages do permit this (e.g. JavaScript, Python, Scala...).

Comment: Are you trying to declare a method inside another method? That is not possible, why would you need that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to nest method implementation code inside Java methods is with [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). In your case this would look like this (code has to be nested inside a class of sorts):

```
public static interface Circle {
    double area(int radius);
}

public static interface Operation {
    int square(int n);
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Circle c = new Circle() {

        Operation op;
        double pi = 3.14;

        public double area(int radius) {
            op = new Operation() {
                public int square(int n) {
                    return n * n;
                }
            };
            int rsquare = op.square(radius);
            return rsquare * pi;
        }
    };
    double s = c.area(5);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take

```
double area(){...}
```

Outside of the `main` method

Java doesn't support nested methods, even if it did, there would be no point to put a nonstatic method in a static method

The closest thing would be nested classes that contain methods, declared in the method

Comment: What about this example with methods setsum and getsum which are nested into main method?

    public class Start{
    
    int i;
    
    void setsum(int i){
    this.i=i;
    }
    
    int getsum()
    {
    return i;
    }
    
    public static void main(String arg[]){
    
    Start s=new Start();
    s.setsum(6);
    int a=s.getsum();
    System.out.println(a);
    
    }
    }

Comment: @OKie In this example you are CALLING the methods from inside another method. But you can't declare them inside!